# Modify list of OrderedDict through for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, ordereddictionary

I am trying to loop over a list of [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and redefine these OrderedDict elements.

To illustrate, consider the list:

```
dict_list = [
    OrderedDict([("key1",1)]),
    OrderedDict([("key1",2)])
]
```

I want to add a new key "key2" on all the dicts.

```
for var in dict_list:
     var["key2"] = 1
```

But that will add this key at the end of the OrderedDict, while I want to add it at the beginning, so I try this:

```
for var in dict_list:
     var = OrderedDict([("key2",1)] + list(var.items()))
```

The change is no remembered outside the for loop (maybe because I am trying to redefine the iterator?)

Comment: Terminology nitpick: `var` is not an iterator, but yes, you are merely *assigning to the variable `var`*, which of course, won't modify `dict_list`. Instead, try `for i, var in enumerate (dict_list):...` then in the loop `dict_list[i] = ...`

Comment: maybe because you don't return the new ordereddict. What do you return out of loop - or function?

Comment: There is no return here, and there shouldn't be. Regardless, even if this were a function, it wouldnt modify dict_list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was struggling on how to call var ^^', what do we call var in this context?

Comment: Mostly I hear people say "the loop variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var["key2"] = 1
var.move_to_end("key2", last=False)
```

Comment: For clarity `last=False` means "add to beginning" ([source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end)).